# Какой смысл в CSP с 'unsafe-inline'?! Практически на всех топовых сайтах такое

Tags: http, безопасность, https, csp

Имею ввиду `'unsafe-inline'` в значении директив `default-src` или `script-src`. Разумеется ни о какой защите от XSS говорить уже не приходится. В моём частном случае я так и не понял чем заменить удобный `onclick`. Ну не загружать же отдельный файл вместо каждого `onclick`, и не конструировать костыли на JS, а `HTMLElement.nonce` насколько я понял вообще очень сырая технология (да и не очень то хотелось париться с очередной криптографией).

Comment: *Разумеется ни о какой защите от XSS говорить уже не приходится.* – почему это?

Comment: Как почему? Потому что `'unsafe-inline'` позволяет включать код прямо в документ. Об этом прямо сказано в спецификации https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/2/#directives

Comment: А его отсутствие – не позволяет. Почему по умолчанию (с CSP) выбрано поведение "не разрешать", полагаю, понятно. Вас интересует, зачем может быть нужно разрешать?

Comment: Нет, я спрашиваю о том, какой вообще смысл в CSP если разрешить `'unsafe-inline'`? (именно это делают на многих топовых сайтах, например на facebook или на яндексе)

Comment: Это лишь одна из многих опций. Непонятно, почему существование одной этой опции должно делать весь заголовок бессмысленным.